# Implementing Single sign on in sapui5 launchpad to JBOSS

Tags: sapui5, sap-gateway, sap-smp

I am a sapui5 developer,Toady Client came up with proposal of single-sign-on.

As i know that single-sign-on is feature of sap gateway(presume configuration are done prior to this).

x-csrf-token can be considered as session id which is set by netweaver gateway.(please correct me if i am wrong).

But in my case let's say application is only accessible to users with 2 roles(one user with role1 can  edit the data, another user with role 2 can only view the data) and i have to deal with jboss DV as backend.

so my question is.. on click on my application tile in the launchpad how java project running in JBoss DV knows about user who logged in and responds with corresponding data?